# Am I correct regarding Aut($Z_n$)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solution-verification

In the following pic-

[image]

shouldn't  it be $\Bbb{Z}_{{p_j}-1}$ instead of $\Bbb{Z}_{p_j}$.

I think so because   Aut$(Z_{p^n}) \cong Z_{p-1} \oplus \underbrace {(Z_p\oplus Z_p \oplus \dots Z_p)}_{n-1\ \text{times}} $.

Am I correct?

Comment: It doesn't look right at all. The automorphism group of a cyclic group of order $p^n$ with $p$ odd is cyclic of order $(p-1)p^{n-1}$ (which is isomorphic to $C_{p-1} \times C_{p^{n-1}}$) and for $p=2$ and $n \ge 2$, it is isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_2^{n-2}$.

Comment: yes. Thanks....